# Model order based on a different model

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

In Django, I have two models; Model B has a primary key OneToOneField relationship with the primary key of model A.

```
class A(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id2 = models.ForeignKey(also a autofield to the field it’s referencing)
    class Meta:
        ordering = [“-id2” , “id”]

class B(models.Model): 
    id = models.OneToOneField(A, primary_key=True)
    class Meta:
        ordering = [???]
```

Is there a way for me to order model B based on Model A’s ordering without replicating data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try maybe this

```
class A(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id2 = models.ForeignKey(also a autofield to the field it’s referencing)
    class Meta:
        ordering = [“-id2” , “id”]

class B(models.Model): 
    id = models.OneToOneField(A, primary_key=True,related_name="A")
    class Meta:
        ordering = ["A__id"]
```

Comment: So unless I add an id2 field referencing to model A’s id2, which I don’t think is allowed anyways, I’m stuck with using related_name, right? I feel like querying would be a hassle, would it not?

Comment: @Yoomama Yes it would so it is possible but not advisable

Comment: @Yoomama you can always define a `queryset` that would do a join on both tables and then order the result accordingly you do not have to always use the default ordering method.

Comment: Hmm. I did not know about that. I’m also clueless as to how to go about it... but how would queryset improve performance in my case since the Table A is constantly updated with writes?

Comment: @Yoomama writes are not the problem if you are not fetching the whole list after each write. Ordering is just the default ordering for the object while fetching lists. You would need to be more specific when the lists is fetched and what data are important.